# How to create data ranges in charts with R?

Tags: r, charts

My data are the 50 largest companies by revenue.
I have their employee count but I can't show it in a chart as they all have a different number of employees. How can I sort the chart to group companies in ranges?

For example: 3 companies with employee count between 1 and 50k, 5 between 50k and 100k etc.

So far I have:

```
plot(table(data$Employee),type="h",xlab="Number of employee", 
     ylab="Employees", main="50 largest companies")
```

But it doesn't make sense as it displays 1 for each employee count.

EDIT

Here is my data:

http://pastebin.com/2mBTdQ0b

The employee part is near the end

Comment: where is some reproducible data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking to plot a histogram of employee count. Take a look at ?hist. Here is an example

```
empl_count <- sample(1:500000,50)
yourbreaks <- seq(0,500000,by=50000)
x <- hist(empl_count,breaks=yourbreaks,plot=F)
x
plot(x, freq=T, axes=F,xlab="Number of employees in thousands", ylab="Frequency",main="50 largest companies")
axis(1,at=yourbreaks,labels=yourbreaks/1000,las=2)
axis(2,at=x$counts,labels=x$counts,las=1)
```